# CakePHP multiple file upload field only uploading one image

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to upload some files using the multiple upload file field. The POST information gets sent correctly and looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Uploads] => Array
        (
            [photos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => image - Copy - Copy.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpALAMwT
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 60892
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => image - Copy.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpoIGtta
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 60892
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => image.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpERTogu
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 60892
                        )

                )
```

And i loop through and insert each one into the database, then upload them using the ID from the database, like this:

```
// Upload Photos
if (!empty($this->request->data['Uploads']['photos'][0]['tmp_name'])){

    foreach($this->request->data['Uploads']['photos']as $photo){

        $property_id = $this->request->data['Property']['ID'];
        $file_name = $photo['name'];
        $file_size = $photo['size'];
        $file_ext = pathinfo($photo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Save to DB
        $this->Property->PropertyImage->save(array(
            'PropertyImage' => array("Live"=>1, 'Number'=>99, "Type"=>'L', "FileType"=>$file_ext, "PropertyID"=>$property_id, 'Source'=>$file_name, 'Size=>'.$file_size)
        ));

        // Upload
        $id = $this->Property->PropertyImage->getLastInsertID();
        $path = intval($id/1000) . '/' . $id . '.' . $file_ext;
        move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imgp/F/'.$path);

    }
}
```

But only one image gets put into the database and uploaded each time, cant work out why the look isn't working right.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the line were you call save()

```
$this->Property->PropertyImage->save(...)
```

call

```
$this->Property->PropertyImage->create();
```

to tell the model to write a new record instead of continue to work with the just saved one.

Comment: Why should it stop? I would also recommend a better way to store the images if you expect lots of them. I recently wrote an article about that: http://cakedc.com/florian_kraemer/2012/02/03/image-saving-and-processing-for-high-traffic-sites

Comment: Do you have the new link to the article?

Comment: @Bear I've copied to my own site as well http://florian-kraemer.net/2012/02/image-saving-and-processing-for-high-traffic-sites/ & http://florian-kraemer.net/2013/08/the-imagine-plugin/